# How to add custom images to JMeter HTML report?

Tags: jmeter, report

JMeter: Adding Custom Images to JMeter HTML report

We are planning to include the application Logo in the JMeter HTML report. Please suggest the approach for this

Please suggest in which configuration files, we can make changes to append the images to HTML file

Answer (score 0):

As of [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) it's only possible to [add a new chart with your own custom metric over time](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#customs_graphs).

All the configuration overrides should go to [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

If you want to add a 3rd-party external image like your company logo or something like this - take a look at [*report-template* folder](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/tree/rel/v5.5/bin/report-template) in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation, you can change the defaults there.

Comment: I am trying to understand from the file index.html.fmkr where the below variables are being referred and how do we add new parameter <table id="generalInfos" class="table table-bordered table-condensed " >
                            <tr>
                                <td>Source file</td>
                                <td>${testFile!""}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Start Time</td>
                                <td>${beginDate!""}</td>
                            </tr>